# Why can't load image from this Url in Android

Tags: java, android, http, android-imageview, android-volley

I have been trying to load the image at this [Url](https://cub.com/content/dam/B2C/enterprisebannerwebsites/Cub/CUB_WK25_HP_BackToSchool.jpg) for several days now but nothing I have tried has been successful. I am using the Volley library and the first thing I tried was a simple...

```
        mImageView.setImageUrl("https://cub.com/content/dam/B2C/enterprisebannerwebsites/Cub/CUB_WK25_HP_BackToSchool.jpg", VolleyImgController.getInstance().getImageLoader());
```

But that returned a blank in the networkimageview.
Along with the following message in the logcat

```
08-27 22:33:49.209    3069-3069/com.supervalu.mobile.android D/Volley﹕ [1] Request.finish: 15308 ms: [ ] https://cub.com/content/dam/B2C/enterprisebannerwebsites/Cub/CUB_WK25_HP_BackToSchool.jpg 0x422b54c3 LOW 1
```

I then tried to create my own HttpStack in case it was an Issue with loading https images using the following code...

```
public static DefaultHttpClient getHttpsClient(){
    // register scheme for http
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("http",new PlainSocketFactory(),80));
    //register scheme for https
    SocketFactory https_socket = new FakeSocketFactory();
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", https_socket,433));

    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    //setting connection timeout.
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, MyConstants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, MyConstants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
    return new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(httpParams,registry),httpParams);

}
```

Which I then passed into this code block

```
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext(),new HttpClientStack(HttpClient.getHttpsClient()));
```

This didn't help either and I got the same response as earlier.

I then downloaded a volley sample project from https://github.com/ogrebgr/android_volley_examples to see if the url would work in their project and it also did not load an image when I plugged it in.

My question is, why am I not able to display an image from this Url?
Is there anything I can do to remedy this?

=====Edit=====
Url Variants I've tried
http://cub.com/content/dam/B2C/enterprisebannerwebsites/Cub/CUB_WK25_HP_BackToSchool.jpg

https://cub.com/content/dam/B2C/enterprisebannerwebsites/Cub/CUB_WK25_HP_BackToSchool.jpg

https://www.cub.com/content/dam/B2C/enterprisebannerwebsites/Cub/CUB_WK25_HP_BackToSchool.jpg

These all respond with a 301 redirect to this url https://www.cub.com/content/dam/B2C/enterprisebannerwebsites/Cub/CUB_WK25_HP_BackToSchool.jpg

I'm thinking the issue may not be with the url string. Is anyone able to load an image from this url in their android app? If so, how did you accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I access the url by chrome, it says that is not secret link. Why not try change the url to `https://www.cub.com/content/dam/B2C/enterprisebannerwebsites/Cub/CUB_WK25_HP_BackToSchool.jpg`

PS: just add `www`to the url header.

updated:
I use [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) and look for [Document](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html), the image is loaded!!!

[image]

PS：Maybe you you need the web ca: `openssl s_client -connect cub.com:443`

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The follow is the code I used to replace that BaseImageDownLoader:

```
    protected HttpsURLConnection createConnection(String url, Object extra) throws IOException {
    String encodedUrl = Uri.encode(url, ALLOWED_URI_CHARS);

    // Load CAs from an InputStream
    // (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
    CertificateFactory cf = null;
    try {
        cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    } catch (CertificateException e1) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();

    }
    // From https://www.washington.edu/itconnect/security/ca/load-der.crt
    InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/cub.crt"));
    Certificate ca = null;
    try {
        try {
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
        } catch (CertificateException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    } finally {
        caInput.close();
    }

    // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
    String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
    KeyStore keyStore = null;
    try {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        try {
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();

        } catch (CertificateException e1) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();

        }

        // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = null;
        try {
            tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(keyStore);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();

        }

        // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
        SSLContext context = null;
        try {
            context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        try {
            context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(encodedUrl).openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
        conn.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
        conn.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
        return conn;
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return null;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried this in chrome, it can not load caused by "https"

try using http schemas

http://www.cub.com/content/dam/B2C/enterprisebannerwebsites/Cub/CUB_WK25_HP_BackToSchool.jpg

Comment: The response from the server is a 301 which redirects back to "https://" no matter what... Are you able to load from that url in your own app?